# How would I go about authenticating a user for an android app?

Tags: authentication

I am creating an android app that has access to an online Database. The initial app activity screen is a login form  where the users credential are validated. If the credentials are valid then the app continues to the next activity. I've looked at OPENID and a few others methods. How would I implement OPENID or a another form of user authentication for my app. I would ultimately like to have a third party take care of user authentication and credential storage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at OAuth?

http://oauth.net/

OAuth Signpost is an android implementation of OAuth
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

Server side, you need to provide an OAuth ready API, if your server is PHP, take a look at
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/